# Xceed PropertyGrid does not clear when bound property is set to null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, propertygrid, xceed

I'm using the Xceed PropertyGrid, which works great, until I set the property to which it is bound to null. This should clear the property grid, but it does not.  Is there something special I need to do to clear the PropertyGrid?

**XAML:**

```
<xctkpg:PropertyGrid
    IsCategorized="True"
    NameColumnWidth="150"
    SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedObject}"
    ShowSearchBox="True"
    ShowSortOptions="False"
    ShowTitle="False" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
#region SelectedObject

    private object _SelectedObject;

    public object SelectedObject
    {
        get { return this._SelectedObject; }

        set
        {
            if (this._SelectedObject != value)
            {
                this._SelectedObject = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.SelectedObject));
            }
        }
    }

#endregion SelectedObject
```

**Elsewhere in the code:**

```
this.SelectedObject = this.SomeObject; <--- the property grid is correctly populated
```

...

```
this.SelectedObject = null; <--- the property grid incorrectly remains populated
```

Comment: Does it hit the `RaisePropertyChanged` line when you set it to `null`?

Comment: This is a known bug, look [here](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1177).